# Creating an MVC 3 Razor - Display Template Library for sharing across multiple projects/solutions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, display-templates

Is it possible to put Display Templates in a separate VS project that can then be referenced by my web site projects. I like using display templates but I don't like the idea of re-use via copy and paste as this soon becomes a headache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) which illustrates a technique allowing you to embed Razor views into separate assemblies and reusing them.

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/ - this is more sophisticated, easier to install from Nuget and works very well.